# Show all options selected by default in a dropdown list

Tags: filter, drop-down-menu, powerbi

I would like to know (by request of our client) if it is possible to modify the behavior of a drop-down list filter. The idea is to see all the options selected by default when the current value is All. Something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Power BI Desktop click on `Select all`, save the report and publish it. This will be the default selection and it will be shown to the user. Just to note, that the result of both selections is equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

you can select all option as shown in the picture and by default it will select ALL values in the slicer.

Click on the Slicer you want to apply and go to  Visualizations menu --> Format Brush --> Seclection controls

[image]

You can do other method:

In Filters you can selet 'All'

[image]